# Algorithm arn does not exist when trying to start AWS Sagemaker training job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-marketplace

When trying to start a training job in sagemaker using AlgorithmEstimator (by inputting the algorithm arn), I get an error saying that the Algorithm arn does not exist. I have tried this with multiple algorithm arns (both obtained from my own algorithms and algorithms from AWS Marketplace) and they all give a similar error message.

I am using sagemaker==2.145.0, both locally and in a sagemaker notebook instance.

I am tried executing this notebook: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/aws_marketplace/using_algorithms/autogluon/autogluon_tabular_marketplace.ipynb

I expected it to run smoothly, but I obtained this error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: Algorithm arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-2:[acc-id]:algorithm/arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-2:[acc-id]:algorithm/autogluon-tabular-v3-5-cb7001bd0e8243b50adc3338deb44a48 does not exist.
```

Comment: For Marketplace algorithms you need to subscribe and accept the end user agreement and terms. Only then it will be available for your account

Comment: I have accepted + subscribed to the Marketplace algorithms. However I still get the same error.

Comment: I was able to run the notebook after subscription in us-east-1 region. Can you try changing region and also check your role permissions.